# Replace current Firestore document

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I've creating a program where you can enter up to 6 persons when registering. And once ur online on the application you can change the names of the persons using textfields. And when I'm clicking on save the program will simply insert the data into Firestore, but thats where the problem occurs.

It insert the data in a new document, and not in the current one. Which is a problem.

So how can I replace documents using Firestore?

Here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func SaveData(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let authentication = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        //Replacing persons
        db.collection("users").document(authentication!)
        .collection("Person").addDocument(data:
        [
           "Name1": person1.text!,
           "Name2": person2.text!,
           "Name3": person3.text!,
           "Name4": person4.text!,
           "Name5": person5.text!,
           "Name6": person6.text!
         ], completion: { (err) in
                    if err != nil
                    {
                        print("Error replacing persons!")
                        return
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("Succeded!")
                    }
            })
    }
```

When I'm "replacing" the data with the new one, it creates a new document, and not replacing the current one. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `addDocument` Firestore will create a new document, as the name of the function implies. To replace the contents of an existing document you must:

1. Have a reference to that specific document.
2. Call `setData()` on that reference.

So say that you want to update the names in a document called `Person1`:

```
db.collection("users").document(authentication!)
.collection("Person").document("Person1").setData([
   "Name1": person1.text!,
   "Name2": person2.text!,
   "Name3": person3.text!,
   "Name4": person4.text!,
   "Name5": person5.text!,
   "Name6": person6.text!
 ], completion: { (err) in
        if err != nil
        {
            print("Error replacing persons!")
            return
        }
        else
        {
            print("Succeded!")
        }
})
```

See the documentation up [setting data for a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). You can also *update* a document, which means that only the fields that you specify are changed. For more on this, see [update data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) in the same documentation page.

Comment: I've tried that, but still adding a new document. I guess the reason for that is because I leave the document field empty like this: .document().setData. But that is because of the documentID, it looks like this: 
>Vta4S2x181oKbe8ZqtTH

And since there is a lot of users its always different. So how can I collect the document id of that? Do you know?

Comment: Calling `setData(...)` does **not** create a new document, but calling `document()` without any argument indeed does. If you don't know the document ID, you can first look it up with a query. But that requires that you know *something* that identifies this specific document within the `Person` collection of that specific user.

Comment: Okay, so I solved it using documentID. When I'm retrieving the data I added a string to collect the document ID, where I later on used in the document like this: ".document(personID)"

Comment: Good to hear Putte.